# What to do in face of total ban on kosher meat?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, dina-dmalchusa-dina

If a country bans shechitah and also bans the importation of kosher meat, do the Jews of that country have to go vegetarian according to dina d'malchuta dina?

Comment: What's the other option?

Comment: They could move, no?

Comment: They could ignore the law.

Comment: This would on its face seem to trigger the "unjust law" clause in dinah malchuta dinah, in which case clandestine kosher slaughter would be halachichally permitted

Comment: @joshk why is it unjust?

Comment: I see three options: obey the law. Disobey the law. Move away. What else is there to do?

Comment: @DoubleAA the "unjust law" clause involves it being specifically against Jews or Jewish practices. A ban on all slaughter, not just Kosher slaughter, would be less clear cut in terms of being permitted to disobey it.

Comment: @ezra the question is whether we're *halachically* permitted to break this civil law; usually we're required to follow the law of the land

Comment: @JoshK Does _dina d'malchusa dina_ apply when the law bans something in Torah?

Comment: @ezra I don't have a better source than the wikipedia article on dina d'malchuta dina, but take a look: Application of the dina to Jews Edit
The Rabbis required "minimal justice" from non-Jewish rulers, as such for the dina to be accepted there were two stipulations.[13] These stipulations were that laws had to be both explicit and universal, to safeguard Jews from gentile laws that could potentially be used against them.[14]

Comment: @ezra  What do you mean?  If the Torah says "Don't do this", and a secular law forces you to do it, you must refuse if it's a ritual matter (Shabbat, kashrut, etc.).

Comment: @ezra Cocaine isn't treif. It's even Pareve. But shouldn't dina demalkhuta apply? How is meat different?

Comment: @DoubleAA There are many more _halachic_ problems with cocaine and other addictive substances besides _kashruth_. :) Not the best example. :/

Comment: @ezra it's still quite sufficient for my needs

Comment: Note that there is no commandment to eat meat.  (No Temple, no Pessah.)